# get the old color scheme from mozilla dev. edition back

Tags: firefox-developer-edition

Ok this is not really a programming question, but is there a way to get the old color scheme from mozilla firefox developer edition back ?

Two weeks ago it changed it scheme in all the developer tools. The tags in the dom are green, the console got an really ugly grey and even the style inspector got such ugly new green selectors.

Is there any way to get the old color scheme with the nice colors back ? (I have no idea which version this was.)

I really hope someone can help me out :(

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible, though you can vote on [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1281118) if you'd like custom color schemes to be supported.